# Is http to http to https redirection secure?

Tags: tls

We have a site that have redirection path like so:

1. http://www.example.com
2. http://www.example.com/
3. https://www.example.com/

Notice how it goes from http to http first (added a `/`), then finally go to https

While ideally it should first go to HTTPS before adding a slash, it is what it is now. Moreover, user final destination is HTTPS so my thinking is it should be secure enough.

I would like to know if the above step would potentially raise any security concerns, and see if hardening is needed. Cheers!

Comment: I think 1+2 is just as safe as only 1; it's within your server, so the protocol doesn't much matter.

Comment: Do you have HSTS set?

Comment: Yes, HSTS is set, thanks for asking

Comment: Why do you redirect to "/"?

Comment: @nobody even HSTS doesn't save you )

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
http://www.example.com
http://www.example.com/
```

There is actually no difference between these from the perspective of the browser and HTTP protocol. A URL consists (among others) of a protocol (`http://`), a hostname (`www.example.com`) and a path. An empty path is not possible and both of the URL shown use the path `/`. So there is no actual redirect between these URL since these are equivalent already.

For more on this see the HTTP standard, specifically [RFC 7321 section 5.3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-5.3.1):  *"If the target URI's path component is empty, the client MUST send "/" as the path within the origin-form of request-target."*.
Note that this only applies to `http://example.com` vs. `http://example.com/`, i.e. empty path vs. `/`. With a path of `/foo` vs. `/foo/` it is different since these will actually result in different requests.

> Moreover, user final destination is HTTPS so my thinking is it should be secure enough.

Since the initial request and response are still done via plain HTTP, they are not protected against manipulation by a man in the middle. For example the response could be modified or a new response injected to direct the client to a different final URL. This actually happens, see for example [Internet Provider Redirects Users in Turkey to Spyware: Report](https://www.securityweek.com/internet-provider-redirects-users-turkey-spyware-report).

In other words: every clear text redirect is one too much. To reduce this attack vector further use [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security).

Comment: That's reassuring, would like to see what RFC would contain this info so I can have it reference to my colleague, thanks!

Comment: @NgSekLong: [RFC 7321 section 5.3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-5.3.1): *"If the target URI's path component is
   empty, the client MUST send "/" as the path within the origin-form of
   request-target. "*. Also, just look at the wire (with wireshark or similar) and the servers log files to see what is actually happening regarding requests and redirects.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, many thanks!

Comment: See also this related question on the Webmasters stack: [Is trailing slash automagically added on click of home page URL in browser?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35643/is-trailing-slash-automagically-added-on-click-of-home-page-url-in-browser)

Comment: In other words, it is the browser "correcting" the first URL automatically by adding the final `/`, exactly like it automatically adds http:// when it's missing. It definitely happens in the browser, not on the server, so there is no "redirect". Note however that it would be very different if there was a path pointing to a directory and the server adding a missing `/` in that case.

Comment: -1 In an HTTP request, the URI is given as string in the header, and this string may or may not contain a trailing slash. Same holds for the redirect URL in the response header. A client will issue another request if it is configured to follow redirects (what web browsers are, but not necessarily command line tools).

Comment: @rexkogitans: May I introduce you to the actual standard? See [RFC 7230 section 3.1.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.1.1) about the request line. The second element is `request-target`. This is defined in RFC 7231 section 5.3 where you have `origin-form`, `absolute-form` and others as choice. `absolute-form` is the one you refer too, which is (as explicitly stated) __used when connecting to a proxy__. For normal requests `origin-form` is used which starts with `absolute-path`. If you don't believe the standard you might also just look at actual traffic.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Whatever the standard says, if the server responds with 301 (or similar) and a Redirect URL (header `location`) which differs from the source URL only in a trailing slash, the client *will* issue another request with exactly the URL stated in the location header.

Comment: @rexkogitans: This  question is about redirecting a request of `http://example.com` to `http://example.com/` and then redirecting the latter one again. The answer is that the first kind of request  is exactly the same as the second request, which also means that the redirect of the first request to the second will never happen - it will be directly redirected to the third (remember: first and second can not be distinguished in the server).

Comment: @rexkogitans: this is not about what your site is intend to do regarding redirects but what actually happens. If you redirect to `http://example.com` the browser will actually access `http://example.com/`. If you enter `http://example.com` in the URL bar the browser will also access `http://example.com/`. Same with `https://` instead of `http://`. This is because there can be no empty `absolute-path` used as `request-target` in the URL. It will be at least `/`. See the standard and look at actual traffic.

Comment: @rexkogitans We are not talking about any trailing slash. Yes, if the URL is `http://example.com/thing` and the server redirects to `http://example.com/thing/`, that's a redirect. But a browser or a command line tool just **cannot** request `http://example.com` with no path at all. That URL is not valid on the wire in HTTP, so it **will** be corrected **by the browser** to append the missing `/` **before it's sent**. There **won't be** any redirect by the server in this instance.

Comment: @rexkogitans Try `curl -v http://example.com` (Yes, it's a real domain). You'll see that the HTTP request is `GET / HTTP/1.1`. Which means the URL it is actually accessing is indeed `http://example.com/`, not `http://example.com`. Again, we're talking about the specific case where there is nothing at all after the domain: that can't happen. If there is a path, then indeed a server-side redirect can happen and means two different requests.

Comment: @jcaron: That's true (so rex's comments are misplaced), but I think the answer would be better if it pointed out 2 thing: (1) This doesn't apply for paths other than `/` vs. empty. Other future readers may also(?) not realize the significance of an empty path vs. `/foo`. (2) The first step is already insecure so it's basically pointless to worry about for security (as other answers point out, including in `/foo` to `/foo/` cases), only performance (saving a network round trip if you redirect directly from `http://example.com/foo` to `https://example.com/foo/`)

Comment: @PeterCordes: good point. I've extended the answer.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich *bump* I missed the point "empty path" versus `/foo` with or without trailing slash.  Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Why does the standard ban `absolute-path` from being empty (and what would happen if a browser _didn't_ automagically correct `http://example.com` to `http://example.com/`?

Comment: @Vikki: A path is basically a specific resource inside a server. An empty path makes semantically not really sense. Since in empty path is invalid specifying one inside a request should result in a 404 bad request.

Comment: @Vikki It would issue a request like `GET HTTP/1.1`. Treating this as equal to `GET / HTTP/1.1` on server side would make parsing the header slightly more complex.

Answer (score 13):

There is no "secure" redirection between http and https. The first step is insecure (http) and can be compromised with a relative ease.

Considering this, it is not really important from security viewpoint if the insecure steps are one or more.

What can be used to improve the situation:

- HSTS : only the first request will be http. Subsequent requests will always go directly to https browser-side.
- advertize the https link. Good if the users are not expected to type it in their browser, but follow a link instead.

Comment: Sorry to be more specific, but I meant to say the 3 redirection are auto redirections. So user landing on `http://www.example.com` is first seemingly auto redirected to `http://www.example.com/`, then to `https://www.example.com/`. It won't really post any security risk since user typing http link will be auto redirected, cheers!

Comment: @NgSekLong since the first request is over HTTP, it is insecure, so it can be intercepted and send to an attacker's server, which *won't* redirect them.

Comment: I see! That's make total sense. Yes we already implemented HSTS and advertised the https link as suggested.

Answer (score 5):

You should not be providing plain-text HTTP service at all, and then there's no redirect problem. [Modern browsers will attempt an HTTPS connection anyway](https://blog.chromium.org/2021/03/a-safer-default-for-navigation-https.html). E.g. if you enter `example.com`, the modern browser attempts https before http. Even if you attempt `http://example.com`, decent browsers (everything modern I think) will attempt `https` if the `http` connection was rejected (i.e. closed port).

Another important thing to remember: any internal links or references you provide from within your site should ideally be relative, but if they are absolute for any reason then they should be `https`-only - browsers routinely reject unsafe redirects to same domain from within secured content.

Corollary: On the firewall protecting your service, make sure that the rule for port http (80) is REJECT, **not** DROP. The latter would cause a connection time-out, and that will provide not only bad user experience, but also it's not common for browsers to retry with https after an http timeout. To prevent participation in reflected traffic DOS attacks, make sure that the outgoing rate for port 80 (and all other ports that REJECT connections rather than DROPping them) is limited per remote IP address. Typically you'd let Cloudflare or somesuch worry about that, though.

Comment: Oh wow, I was about to write a snarky comment about how this is BS, but I looked it up and it's true. Glad I learned something today.

Comment: Thanks for the info, will investigate on the firewall REJECT option which seems very promising, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

It's no less secure than a direct http to https redirect. Technically an attacker may get two chances to intercept the redirect - but if someone is attacking your network, it is usually all or nothing. Either they intercept both redirects (just as bad as a intercepting one) or neither.

Comment: What we have here is what looks like a late duplicate of a previous answer but only this one says something about the actual threat model.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is secure.

Security is a *direction*, not a destination.

Sure it's good to get people to use https.  So redirecting from http to https is *more secure* than keeping users in http without redirection.

But it's a *whole lot better* to use HSTS, and put your domain in the HSTS preload list: https://hstspreload.org/

You could go another step further still, and **completely shut off** your http (non-tls) server.  (Gasp)  How uncouth!

Or perhaps take it to the *most secure* option, and host only a simple message on http (non-tls) that instructs the user that you will never provide non-https content and to manually type https://yourdomain.com to get to the site and explains why redirects are bad.

That last step has the bonus of gradually changing user behavior to expect https and try that first.

It still won't *be secure*.  But it will be *more secure.*

Comment: The 'simple message' should not match the style of your brand.  There is value in it causing the user discomfort and pause.  If you make the redirect easy you enable behavior that makes the attacker's job easier.

Comment: Correct and valuable answer to the title question; other answers are myopic but otherwise good.